# How to install downloaded packages in terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/can-you-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

I have packages that I have downloaded from the internet and for some reason they won't install inside of Ubuntu Software Center.  My question is what command should I use to install a package inside of terminal.  I have already downloaded the packages and I need and I just need the command that will install the package, not `apt-get`.

Comment: To vague... it really depends on what type of installation is required for that package (but all of them will already have been asked on AU. DEB is normal Ubuntu. Example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/can-you-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line

Comment: @Sam-Mercier: If the package does not install from Ubuntu software center then you may not be able to install it from terminal either. Try to figure out why the package is not installing. One reason may be that your system architecture different than one the package is built for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dpkg` - package manager for Debian.

`dpkg -i yourpackage.deb` to install a package.

Comment: Okay.  That sounds about right.  I had already tried that command, but I think I forgot the .deb.

Comment: Make sure to use the full file name, not only the package name.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the folder containing the package

```
cd Desktop/System\ Files/
```

Type `ls` to get a list of files in the current directory to be sure you're in the right place

Then `dpkg -i PotatoKiller3000.deb` to install.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are a gui guy install `gdebi` and make deb packages open with gdebi.